# NHibernate mapping customization

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using Nhibernate 3.3.1 and I need to ensure that none of my string columns would have lengths smaller than 15 i.e.

I'm trying to check it no AfterMapProperty/BeforeMapProperty events of ModelMapper, but as I know Length property is private of PropertyMapper class or some base class of it.

I'm tryign to avoid to use Reflection to access private property to get Length and check it.

Can you help me?

Comment: If the answer from Baz1nga isn't what you were looking for, please clarify if you are trying to write a unit test to verify your mappings, or a runtime test to validate the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `check` attribute to achieve this.. In your mapping file you need to define something like this:

```
<property name="Foo" type="string">
    <column name="foo" check="DATALENGTH(foo) > 15"/>
</property>
```

This will create a check constraint.. I am not too sure about the DATALENGTH method but you can confirm that..

Refer section 20.1.1 of NH docs here: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to mention that I need it on db schema, that is generated by NH.